# Adding second instance of Firefox with Marionette (change port)

Tags: python, firefox, firefox-marionette

I'm having great difficulties creating two instances of firefox via marionette. Having one instance works fine:

Starting up Firefox with marionette enabled:

```
firefox.exe -marionette
```

Controlling it with python:

```
from marionette import Marionette
client = Marionette('localhost', port=2828)
client.start_session()
client.execute_script("alert('o hai there!');")
```

Now I'd like to add a second client alongside the current one, a [quick search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mozilla.tools.marionette/2JdqdzpUWqY/gtq86DqeEQAJ) resulted in the --address command:

```
firefox.exe -marionette --address=localhost:2829
```

Trying to control it via python:

```
from marionette import Marionette
client = Marionette('localhost', port=2829)
client.start_session()
client.execute_script("alert('o hai there!');")
```

I can't seem to get this to work, however:

```
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you do `telnet localhost 2829` to check if the server is running on 2829?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use different profiles to make firefox listen on different ports.
Edit `<path-to-profile>/prefs.js` add the following and save **when firefox is not using this profile**;

```
user_pref("marionette.defaultPrefs.port", 2829);
```

Now, start firefox as;

```
firefox -marionette --profile <path-to-profile> --new-instance&
```

To create a new profile;

```
$ mkdir new_profile
$ firefox --profile new_profile --new-instance
```

and close firefox. Now you'll have `new_profile/prefs.js`

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since the previous reply, so a small update

For now (Firefox version 103+) preference have to  be set is called

```
marionette.port
```

so, you have to set

```
user_pref("marionette.port", 2829);
```

All procedure looks like:

```
$ firefox -CreateProfile "p2829 /tmp/ff_p2829"
$ vi /tmp/ff_p2829/prefs.js #new file
  > enter user_pref("marionette.port", 2829); 
$ firefox -marionette -profile /tmp/ff_p2829/ -new-instance
```

and now firefox marionette server listening on port **2829**