# Multiple Instances of Firefox with Marionette/Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

I would like to open up multiple instances of Firefox using Selenium in Python and run them in parallel. After updating to Firefox 47.0, it seems that we now [have to use the Marionette WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47) for Firefox+Selenium. Before using Marionette, I could easily create new Firefox instances from within Python/Selenium simply by calling `webdriver.Firefox()` multiple times. After switching to Marionette though, only the first instance works. If a second instance is opened, I receive the following error:

> WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette

After issuing the error, that instance dies, while the most recently-called instance lives on. Looking around, it appears that the problem lies in the ports that Marionette uses, where new instances keep trying to hit the same port that the original one was using. I saw that there's a way to alter the ports being used by [going through prefs.js and creating separate profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514778/adding-second-instance-of-firefox-with-marionette-change-port). However, I was wondering whether there was a way to do it from completely within Python (analogous to this [Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510794/selenium-marionette-driver-unreachablebrowserexception-upon-second-launch)).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug with selenium/marionette projects so they can fix this issue, as this is obviously not intended.

Comment: Thanks! I have filed a bug with them.

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: I ended up downgrading to Firefox 46.0, but according to [this](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/pull/112), the issue has been resolved. I haven't tried it out yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue reported here:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1453

Basically you need to run with a debug firefox build + trace marionette logging to get more details. Or maybe you're hitting the same.